# Sandstorm sandbox?

Tags: sandbox, configuration, einstein-analytics

Fiddling around the sandbox details I stumbled upon an unknown option.
[image: Sandstorm]

It reads:

*Sandbox Options*

*Is a Sandstorm copy?*

Googling around it says it has something to do with Wave analytics but couldn't find much info about it.

What does this option do?

Comment: No Darude answers please :D

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you look at some [older release notes](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_deployment_sandstorm.htm#rn_sandstorm), it becomes slightly clearer what exactly Sandstorm may be:

> We’ve rebuilt our sandbox copy engine to optimize performance, scalability, and customer success. The new engine impacts Full sandboxes as they are created and existing Full sandboxes as they are refreshed.
>
> ...
>
> Several enhancements to the copy engine make sandbox creation and refresh faster and minimize sandbox inconsistencies. These improvements are available on a rolling basis during the Summer ’15 release.
>
> [Features include:]
>
> #### Intelligent Routing
>
> #### New Data Copy Framework
>
> #### New Post-Copy Framework
>
> #### Progress Tracking

My guess, based on this and the two subsequent release notes is that SFDC built a great new way to make Sandboxes better and quicker, but it failed to work properly for Analytics Cloud, so they [gave users an override](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_bi_sandbox.htm).  Now, it seems like [they've fixed it](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_bi_sandstorm.htm), but they forgot to remove the checkbox from the layout (or maybe kept it intentionally for some reason).

Anyway, based on that history, I'd say, "Ignore the field - it's default and you should just keep it unless your support rep gives you a way to override it for some reason."

As for the name, my guess is that "Sandstorm" is a pun on "Sandbox." And it just sounds cool.  I'd assume it has nothing to do with the hash function mentioned in the [earlier answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/123241/7195).

Answer (score 4):

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_bi_sandstorm.htm

> When you use the Sandbox to test Wave Analytics functionality, sandbox
>   copy now uses the new Sandstorm algorithm.

Although I have have not been able to find any information directly related to what the "Sandstorm algorithm" actually is.

Unless this is it:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SANDstorm_hash

> The SANDstorm hash[1] is a cryptographic hash function designed in
>   2008 by Mark Torgerson, Richard Schroeppel, Tim Draelos, Nathan
>   Dautenhahn, Sean Malone, Andrea Walker, Michael Collins, and Hilarie
>   Orman for the NIST SHA-3 competition.
>
> The SANDstorm hash was accepted into the first round of the NIST hash
>   function competition, but was not accepted into the second round.[2]

http://energy.sandia.gov/wp-content/gallery/uploads/SANDstorm_Submission_2008_10_30.pdf

> The SANDstorm hash family is designed for maximal cryptographic
>   strength and high speed on most common architectures

Comment: Marked this as correct due to its completeness, but it still remains a mystery it seems